# Missing reference to netstandard for Cppsharp program

Tags: cppsharp

I'm trying to start my first project with Cppsharp using Visual Studio 2015, following the getting started guide.

The steps I followed were to:

1. Create new C# console project
2. Install Cppsharp using Nuget
3. Add references to Dlls into the project
4. Create C# source file based on the example in this old [post](https://github.com/mono/CppSharp/issues/82)

Whilst the example in the post is old, it still seems to be consistent with the getting started guide. The full program is listed below.

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

using CppSharp;

namespace CppSharpTest
{
    class Program
    {

        class DllDemoGenerator : ILibrary
        {
            static void Main(string[] args)
            {
                ConsoleDriver.Run(new DllDemoGenerator());
            }

            void Setup(Driver driver)
            {
                var options = driver.Options;
                options.GeneratorKind = LanguageGeneratorKind.CSharp;
                options.LibraryName = "DllDemo";
                options.Headers.Add("DllDemo.h");
                options.Libraries.Add("DllDemo.lib");
            }

            public void SetupPasses(Driver driver) { }

            public void Preprocess(Driver driver, CppSharp.AST.Library lib) { }

            public void Postprocess(CppSharp.AST.Library lib) { }
        }

    }
}
```

However, I am already facing errors [See image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wR2io.png):

```
CS0012  C# The type 'Object' is defined in an assembly that is not referenced. You must add a reference to assembly 'netstandard, Version=2.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=...'
```

I was not able to find a way to add this reference. One solution I found proposed to target a higher .NET version (4.7.2) and I tried this, but the error still remains.

Can anyone help to overcome this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Posted the same question on the Github page and was recommended to upgrade from VS2015

Installing VS2019 removed this error